# How safe is the thread local in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

In our multi tenant Rails 4.2 app, we would like to define a thread local `current_token` for `User` model and intend to use it through out the whole app. Here is the how the `current_token` is defined:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current_token=(token)
    Thread.current['current_token'] = token
  end

  def self.current_token
    Thread.current['current_token']
  end
end
```

The token is retrieved with `User.current_token`. It is vital to keep `User.current_token` thread safe and alive throughout the lifespan of a user session. It is pointed out that the thread local may be cleared up by some web server such as `puma`. We would like to get feedback from the community about how sound is the thread local in real production. What kind of problem we should be aware of (and possible solution if there is one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thread.current` per se is secure. The risk of `Thread.current` is that you have to use it correctly, because it doesn't reset automatically at the end of a request. Some examples:

- Imagine you set a token in `Thread.current` in one request and do not set to an other token in the next (perhaps because there was no token in the next request), then the old token will still be available.
- Or you plan to nullify `Thread.current` at the end of each request to ensure each request starts with a blank `Thread.current`. Will happen if a request fails with an exception, does it still get nullified?

It is just error-prone to work with `Thread.current` directly and there is the risk of exposing data from one request (one user) to a later request (user) on the same server.

You might want to check the [RequestStore gem](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) that internally uses `Thread.current`, but warps it with some layers of security.

Comment: The carry-over of an old token by thread.current is a real problem. If `thread.current` is cleared and reset in `before_action` and cleared in a `after_action` in one controller, does it eliminate the risk?

Comment: Mostly, but you also have to think about the middleware. Just have a look how the [RequestStore gem](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store/blob/master/lib/request_store/middleware.rb) handles this.

Comment: Does the RequestStore gem eliminate 2 issues in your post? Just want to confirm. I read a few post about RequestStore gem and was not quite clear about the use of the gem. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, `RequestStore` eliminates this issues, therefore I suggested to use it instead of building something with `Thread.current` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of an issue with puma and thread locals. You might want to use the [sentient_user gem](https://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user) since its behavior is very close to what you're describing. The only difference is that instead of keeping around a token, you keep around the whole user.

I will note that this pattern is basically a global variable, so it acts like an unstated parameter to any method that uses it. But it can be nice for auditing, so that it is always available no matter where you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the the comments.